# R - Converting a multidimensional array to vector and back to multidimensional array

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

I have an R array `start_arr` with `dim`ensions `i` x `j` x `k` representing number of rows, number of columns and the depth respectively. Each dimension is named. I can to convert this array to a (1-dimensional) vector `intermediate_vec`. I then need to convert this 1D vector back into the original `i` x `j` x `k` array `end_arr`. I'm just looking for generic functions `array2vec` and `vec2array` to do the transformation in a way that preserves how elements are arranged when going from array to vector to array (i.e. that the element at 1,1,1 goes to vector element 1 and back to array element 1,1,1; element at 1,2,1 goes to vector element 2 and back to array element 1,2,1 etc). The particular way the elements are placed in `intermediate_vec` isn't important, as long as they end up in the exact same positions in `end_arr` as in `start_arr`.

I can do this with a C-like iterative syntax but I'm sure there's some declarative way of doing this in R that's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Suppose we have array `arr` as shown in the first line. Then use `c` to convert to a vector `vec` and perform the transformation of adding 100 to each element.  Then reshape it back with the same names giving `arr2`.

```
arr <- array(1:24, 2:4, dimnames = list(letters[1:2], LETTERS[1:3], month.abb[1:4]))
vec <- c(arr)
arr2 <- replace(arr, TRUE, vec + 100)

# check 
all(arr2 - arr == 100)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** This would also work:

```
arr2a <- array(vec + 100, dim(arr), dimnames = dimnames(arr))

identical(arr2, arr2a)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is `c(arr)` deterministic in the sense that it has a fixed way of converting elements of `arr` to elements in the vector (e.g. row by row etc)?

Comment: Yes, it is in reverse odometer order, i.e. the leftmost index varies fastest.  If `arr` were a matrix that means column by column.